# Extend selection to keep whole groups together

Tags: language-agnostic, relational-algebra

Suppose I have a relation with columns `ID`, `GROUP_ID`, and `DATA`; {`ID`} is a key. I expose to my users some way of selecting a subset of rows based on however they'd like, but I have to extend their selection to always include whole groups. What I'm doing at the moment (where `filter` is the user-supplied function and `r` is my original relation):

```
r' = r ⋉ π{GROUP_ID} (r ⋉ π{ID} (filter r))
```

(or, using function names:

```
r' = semiJoin r (project {GROUP_ID} (semiJoin r (project {ID} (filter r))))
```

)

Is there a way to get the same result while avoiding the double-semijoin on `r`? Since it's user-supplied, I don't want to "trust" the function `filter`; in particular, I don't want to require `filter r` to

- have the same columns as `r`
- have {`ID`} as a key
- not come up with `ID`s that are not in `r`

The only requirement I want is that `r` has a column `ID`.

Comment: Please give all constraints. Eg if {ID} is a candidate key then `r ⋉ π{ID} (filter r)` = `filter r`.

Comment: `filter` is user-supplied, so I want to make as few assumptions about `filter r` as possible. As long as its result contains an `ID` column, it should work.

Comment: Please give all constraints. Also, give say exactly what is permitted for "filter r". The more constraints and limitations, the more options for simplifying your query.

Comment: @philipxy: I tried adding more detail; let me know what else you have in mind.